# How i can create while loop as SINGLE LINE for command-line /bin/sh

Tags: while-loop, sh

I can't create the cycle as single line in /bin/sh

I tried:

`while true; do; sleep 1; done`

How I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want it to just `sleep 1`, then remove the ; after the `do`.

If you want it to actually run a command and then `sleep 1`, then add the command after the `do` like so:

`while true; do echo "hi"; sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra semi-colon after the `do`.

What you're need is `while true; do sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 1):

`do` here is not a command that needs to be terminated; it *is* a special terminator (part of `sh`'s grammar) to signify the end of the command list that forms the condition. For instance, the following is legal:

```
while echo foo; echo bar; true; do sleep 1; done
```

Without `do`,

```
# Hypothetical example. This is not valid code.
while echo foo; echo bar; true; sleep 1; done
```

there would be no way to determine where the condition ends and the body begins.

Comment: The second example isn't intended to work; the `do` was intentionally left out to demonstrate why it is necessary.